# mix awk command in shell script while loop and the variables doensn't keep their values after the loop?

Tags: shell, awk, while-loop

Hi guys sorry for the awkward title but I think it is a bit subtle to describe. So here is my problem, I want to keep a count (i) in a while loop which reads input from awk, and then print the value of i after the loop. However i becomes back to zero after the loop. Below is a simplified version of my program, in reality I also did some string matching inside the loop so that some lines are skipped and i does not increment.

I have tried to remove awk and do another ordinary while loop and i's value is kept after the loop, therefore I believe it's not due to some syntax error.

Any idea is great appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=();
i=0;
awk -F '{print $1}' SOMEFILE | while read var
do
  echo $var;
  arr[i]=$var;
  i=$((i+1));
  echo $i;
done
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the while loop is in a pipeline, it is running as a subprocess, and the value of i is local to that subprocess.  There are several ways to keep the value; use a named pipe instead of running while in a pipeline, use process substitution, or use an interpolating heredoc.  Here's an example of the latter:

```
while read var; do ... done << EOF
$( awk ... )
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks William, could you elaborate a bit? I'm quite new to shell script, for your example, are you suggesting to put awk after while loop?

Comment: nvmd, I have modify my program as follows and it works.Thanks:)
    `#!bin/bash

    i=0;
    arr=();

    while read var 
    do
      echo $var;
      arr[i]=$var;
      i=$((i+1));
    done << EOA
    $(awk -F '{print $1}' DEMOIN) 
    EOA

    echo $i;`

Comment: @ArrowCen: If you're using Bash, ksh or zsh, you can use process substitution which William mentioned but didn't illustrate: `while ... done < <(awk ...)`.